# Unable to override list-style-type

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, nav

I have some HTML with pre-existing styles in css.  I need to override the list-style (there's some funny looking bullet points) but I can't seem to figure out how.

```
<!-- pre-existing css style sheets-->
<link href = "css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.doj.state.wi.us/sites/default/files/css/css_xE-rWrJf-fncB6ztZfd2huxqgxu4WO-qwma6Xer30m4.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.doj.state.wi.us/sites/default/files/css/css_Q7R7Blo9EYqLDI5rIlO_T3uTFBjIXjLpcqMHjTvVdmg.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.doj.state.wi.us/sites/default/files/css/css_BRhQSG-b-QpoRSwrSBwmFx6dU3gjEZca4NFu_UQo2-Q.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.doj.state.wi.us/sites/default/files/css/css_fEIYHf7a6__HmaZI0WMfFyuL6hwZU7kJ4ooi1KzkINI.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.doj.state.wi.us/sites/default/files/css/css_FHu0mvAhlYyqLJqNhrBbiHhehxLefpaK6N2l45DULVU.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.doj.state.wi.us/sites/default/files/css/css_bG9BErYV7KOPQxmg--DBVGPBq9-iGTGLJVm90z3JQX0.css" media="all" />
<!-- my css-->
<link href = "css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 

<nav class="navbar" style='float:left'>
      <div class="container-fluid" width='300px'>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
           
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left " id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navText " id="myList" style='list-style-type: none'>
                <li ><a href="production/index.html" id="navText">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="research/index.html" id="navText">Staff</a></li>
                <li><a href="education/index.html" id="navText">Data Dashboards</a></li>
                <li><a href="people/index.html" id="navText">Current Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

I can't seem to get override the existing styling bullet points in the lists. I've the following, and none work:

```
#myList {
        list-style-type: none !important
    }

#navText {
        list-style-type: none !important
    }

#navText li {
        list-style-type: none !important
    }

ul {
    list-style-type: none !important
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Note that #ids must be unique (one per page) so you can't use the same ID on several elements.

Comment: The Bootstrap `navbar nav` element already uses `list-style: none`. What CSS are you trying to override?

Comment: The odd looking 'shield' bullet points on this website:  https://www.doj.state.wi.us/dles/bjia/bureau-justice-information-and-analysis

Comment: I would figure adding a new rule with list-style: none would be able to remove them, but I can't get them to go away.

Comment: That link doesn't work. "server IP address could not be found"

Comment: odd, works for me?

Comment: The whole Wisconsin Department of Justice website is unreachable for me in the UK. Are you blocking IPs outside the US?

Comment: hm, no idea.. sorry!